# Explicit struct in C# requires double init of value

Tags: c#

The following C# struct is used to represent a union of color components and the 32bit color value itself. The problem is that the compiler gives the error:

> Error CS0171  Field 'Color.ARGB' must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller

Is it possible to get rid of this error without initialize the data twice? Is this expected behavior of C#? If I init twice, will the JIT detect the dual init and only do the second one?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Color
{
    public Color(byte r, byte g, byte b, byte a = 0xff)
    {
        ARGB = 0; // The init I shouldn't have to do
        A = a;
        R = r;
        G = g;
        B = b;
    }

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte B;
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte G;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte R;
    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte A;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint ARGB;

    public static readonly Color Red = new Color(255, 0, 0);
    public static readonly Color Green = new Color(0, 255, 0);
    public static readonly Color Blue = new Color(0, 0, 255);
}
```

Comment: What double init? I don't see any

Comment: The compiler error requires me to add one. That is the problem. It wants an init of ARGB even though it is already initialized by writing the individual parts A, R, G and B.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: The code is using struct layout attributes to violate type safety.  field ARGB and fields A, R, G, B have the same memory.

Comment: Exactly, that's the point of a union ... but it doesn't give the compiler the right to force me to initialize the memory twice.

Comment: @maloo: Your statement that the compiler does not have the right to do so is completely and utterly false, so today would be a good day to stop believing it. There is no charter of rights and freedoms that forces compiler developers to implement optimizations you happen to like!

Comment: @EricLippert To be honest, I did look at the attributes, but the first thing that comes to my mind is: compiler ignores attributes, so it would be the same if they weren't there.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: That is the correct analysis, yes.  Maloo wishes the compiler to notice that all four bytes of the structure have been written by the end of the constructor, but the compiler does not care at all how many bytes are in the structure. The compiler cares about there being five fields, and it only sees four of them written to.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks, always interesting reading your replies.

Comment: @EricLippert is it a guarantee that those assignments inside the constructor execute in that order?  Its not really that much overhead to create the uint on demand from the other four properties, and that would avoid a potential scenario where ARGB is written after A,R,G and B thus zeroing out the color.  Even if its guaranteed that they execute in that order, I had to look at it too long to figure out what the problem even was... seems dubious to do it this way in C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into below Microsoft link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0843

It says,

> To assign a value to an automatically-implemented property from a
>   constructor, you must first invoke the default constructor to create
>   the object.

Doing below change will resolve your issue. call default constructor.

```
 public Color(byte r, byte g, byte b, byte a = 0xff):this()
 {
         A = a;
         R = r;
         G = g;
         B = b;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, nicer solution than having to init twice. Just hope JIT won't do the init to defaults if overwritten in the parametric constructor.

Answer (score 9):

> Is it possible to get rid of this error without initialize the data twice?

Yes and no.

The supposition here is that the members are not already "initialized twice". When you get the new struct from the memory allocator -- either from the heap or the stack -- it will be automatically zeroed out.

As Naidu's answer notes, calling the default constructor indicates to the compiler "the runtime must zero this thing out if it is not already; I wish to assert that I am fine with any portion of the object not written to by the constructor being left in its default state ".

In practice, typically the jitter has already initialized to zero, so typically there is no extra initialization done. However, the behaviour that memory allocators automatically initialize state to zero is runtime-implementation-dependent. Similarly it is an implementation-dependent behaviour whether or not the jitter can optimize away the zero-out behaviour if *it* knows that every field is initialized.

There are subtleties here. Suppose for example the memory is not zeroed out because the jitter has deduced that your constructor writes every field. **Now suppose a thread abort exception is thrown halfway through the constructor**. Is it possible for another thread to observe the not-zeroed-out, not-written-by-you state of the object? What hellish behaviour might that wreak, if in fact it is possible? Give that some thought.

> Is this expected behavior of C#?

Yes.

The compiler has no idea whatsoever that you're creating a type-unsafe union. It doesn't know the meanings of those attributes.

> If I init twice, will the JIT detect the dual init and only do the second one?

There are many different jitters on many different platforms. If you want an answer to your question, **try it on all of them with all possible configurations and see what happens**.

Regardless, you are likely worrying about nothing important. **Writing zeros into memory is pretty fast**. Doing an unnecessary zero write is probably not the bottleneck in your program.

Comment: Maybe I added some confusion by not adding the "second" init in my constructor. I understand that all memory is zeroed by GC/JIT/whatever. I didn't even consider that as an init. What I ment was having to do two explicit inits ARGB and A, R, G, B. I guess you could say this would make it tripple init ;). Solution given by Naidu was a nice one I overlooked by focusing on the error.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the detailed write up on the subject.

Comment: @maloo: Ah, I thought you understood that the zero initialization happens and that you were trying to encourage the jitter to avoid it.  Whether the jitter does so or not, I do not know; you'll have to check the various implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.SkipInit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.skipinit), available since .NET 5. It is supposed to actually skip zero-initialization for bytes you're going to initialize anyway:

```cs
public Color(byte r, byte g, byte b, byte a = 0xff)
{
    Unsafe.SkipInit(out ARGB);
    A = a;
    R = r;
    G = g;
    B = b;
}
```